# ModalViewController not being present to user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, modalviewcontroller

I am building a modal view with the following frame...

```
_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
[_authController addSubview:_webView];

[self presentModalViewController:_authController animated:YES];
```

Should the Modal View automatically be placed in front of any other view that is currently in the superview view stack?

This modal view works in an example app that i am going off of, but it will not show if I try to present it within my custom app.

EDIT:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame = %f, %f, %f, %f", _webView.view.frame.origin.x, _webView.view.frame.origin.y, _webView.view.frame.size.width, _webView.view.frame.size.height]);

if (_webView)
{
    [self presentModalViewController:_webView animated:YES];
}

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame = %f, %f, %f, %f", _webView.view.frame.origin.x, _webView.view.frame.origin.y, _webView.view.frame.size.width, _webView.view.frame.size.height]);
```

this has this output...

frame = 0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 416.000000 <-- Before presentModalViewController

frame = 480.000000, 0.000000, 480.000000, 320.000000 <-- After presentModalViewController

Comment: Had to rework the entire prototype to fix the problem, no good answer found.  Something between how I was Drawing one view and the next that was causing massive problems.  I was happy I reworked the prototype.  I found a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to use `UIWebView` (which inherits from `UIView`) as the modal view controller, which expects a `UIViewController` instance instead.  Using a view controller with the webView as its view should let you display it.

Comment: @slev, sorry about that it is a view controller that is being presented to it.  i was trying to show what I was doing and i copied and pasted the wrong thing in.  it should be the view controller that contains the _webView.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about.  Is the view controller being shown and the webView isn't or is none of it showing?  Just trying to narrow down what may be the cause

Comment: @slev, see the edit above.  I guess there is something being adjusted wrong.  I can see a small corner of the view being presented in the lower left corner, but when i made the adjustment from the edit above, then it showed as it should, so I am not sure where to look to make the proper correction.

Comment: What kind of modal presentation type is it?  I've had issues like that where I present the modal view in the Form style and it crops my xib file.  Also, when is this being called?  If it's being called when the app starts, there's a chance that the app hasn't loaded enough for the modal screen to show properly

Comment: @slev, see above for new edit.  none of this is making sense, but I know it is something simple I am missing.  I am loading a view controller, which has two buttons on it (both will present a modal view controller).  when I click one to establish the ModalViewController the frame is as stated above...from the app delegate it gets presented as it should, but from the loading the main view controller with the buttons from another view controller leads to the 0,0,0,0 frame.

Comment: That is definitely odd behavior, sending your view to the bottom corner.  From what's given in your question, it's hard to really diagnose what's going on.  I would imagine it's something to do with how the view controller is initialized or set.  But again, it's a bit hard to tell.  Also, only because I used to do the same thing until I realized there was a much easier way, you don't have to write out each value in your logs for the frame.  `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(someView.frame));` gives you the same thing and is a lot easier to write out